# Why does a header location on admin_head remove the query var I'm setting in the location?

Tags: php, query, query-variable

I have the following code which I thought would load the location with a query var of saved=1.

```
public function __construct() {

    add_action( 'admin_head', array( $this, 'test' ) );

}

public function test() {

    if( $_GET['test'] == 1 ) {

        header( "Location: admin.php?page=my-page&saved=1" );
        exit;

    }

}
```

I am expecting to go to:

http://localhost/test/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-page&test=1

And the resulting page to be loaded as:

http://localhost/test/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-page&saved=1

But the query var gets removed? Why?

Comment: `admin_head` is much too late to output a header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to perform any redirects, you have to send your header before site sends any output.

`admin_head` is an action that allows you to print your custom code inside `<head>` tag of admin sites. But if it's inside of `<head>`, then some output is already sent to the browser, so you can't perform any redirections any more.

As you can see here [Actions Run During an Admin Page Request](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_an_Admin_Page_Request), the `admin_head` is called after the scripts and styles are already printed.

So you should run your code using some hook that is fired before any output is sent to the browser. You can use `wp` hook for example.

PS. Another thing is that you shouldn't use `header( "Location: admin.php?page=my-page&saved=1" );`. Using [`wp_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) would be much nicer way to do this.

Comment: I have added this to action on current_screen, before headers sent and after I have the current screen global. Thanks for your help.